# displaying sql results by a group based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have in my table, say thousands of records. I want to display records together by city. It's a lot more complicated then that, since I need it displayed in alphabetical order as well based on customer name. How do I achieve this? Group BY seems to want to give me a total instead of displaying each of my records. so..

```
mark zuck  some city
john smith cherryville
bill gates some city
jane doe   cherryville
```

should return

```
bill gates some city
mark zuck some city

jane doe cherryville
john smith cherryville
```

This is an over-simplification but the idea stands.

Comment: `select * from YourTable order by cityColumn, customerName`

Comment: Can you add your best not working attempt as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by is for aggregations. There is no aggregation in your query. You just want your output to be sorted. In this case, Order By well fits for the purpose.

```
select * from table1 
order by city, customer
```

In english, get all table1 data sorted by first city, then customer